# Can I play Youtube Offline Videos in my App

Tags: android-youtube-api

I am trying to make an video app that will have a button on whose click I can save the video in Youtube offline mode and can play that video from my app.

Answer (score -1):

This might be illegal:

You could use an API like [this YoutubeExtractor](https://github.com/flag) which allows you to download the videos.

See the original (your question is a duplicate) post 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube).

Comment: Sure, if you want to get sued by YouTube and/or the video copyright holders.

Comment: I disagree. Terms and legal considerations are entirely appropriate to raise.

Comment: I know this API but I do Not want to Download Youtube Video Just want to save them in YouTube Offline Videos and play from their.

Comment: I am sorry, but this function is integrated in the indian Youtube App version, there is a little downloadbutton under the video, what would you need an app or?

Comment: Yes i want to develop such app

Comment: What exactly is your question then? You already have this option in the app; the other way is to download them yourself is an API, which might be illegal.